# How can I enable ignite-geospatial module within Ignite Cluster on Kubernetes using GridGain Community?

Tags: kubernetes, geospatial, ignite, gridgain, apacheignite

#### Background

I am running an Ignite Cluster within Kubernetes and wish to use Java Thick Client to load geospatial objects into an Ignite Cache. I succeed on local deployments where ignite-geospatial module is loaded from GridGain external repository, but I encounter errors on spatial indexing when attempting the same workflow in Kubernetes. I suspect it is due to the `ignite-geospatial` module not accessible to Ignite Nodes, but I am unsure how to confirm or troubleshoot.

I am using GridGain Community 8.8.29.

I have tried including the following OPTION_LIBS in the deployment YAML:

- ignite-geospatial
- ignite-geospatial-ext

Deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"ignite-cluster","namespace":"ignite"},"spec":{"replicas":2,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"ignite"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"ignite"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"OPTION_LIBS","value":"ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http"},{"name":"CONFIG_URI","value":"file:///ignite/config/node-configuration.xml"}],"image":"gridgain/community:latest","name":"ignite-node","ports":[{"containerPort":47100},{"containerPort":47500},{"containerPort":49112},{"containerPort":10800},{"containerPort":8080}],"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/ignite/config","name":"config-vol"}]}],"serviceAccountName":"ignite","terminationGracePeriodSeconds":100000,"volumes":[{"configMap":{"name":"ignite-config"},"name":"config-vol"}]}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-15T11:42:44Z"
  generation: 1
  name: ignite-cluster
  namespace: ignite
  resourceVersion: "404448299"
  uid: 6b30b411-b6bb-49e1-b58a-b656e3c53587
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: ignite
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: OPTION_LIBS
          value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http,ignite-geospatial
        - name: CONFIG_URI
          value: file:///ignite/config/node-configuration.xml
        image: gridgain/community:8.8.29
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: ignite-node
        ports:
        - containerPort: 47100
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 47500
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 49112
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 10800
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /ignite/config
          name: config-vol
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: ignite
      serviceAccountName: ignite
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 100000
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: ignite-config
        name: config-vol
```

Still, I encounter the ClassNotFound Exception for GridH2SpatialIndex:

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2SpatialIndex
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2Utils.createSpatialIndex(H2Utils.java:364)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2TableDescriptor.createUserIndex(H2TableDescriptor.java:442)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2TableDescriptor.createUserIndexes(H2TableDescriptor.java:392)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.SchemaManager.createTable(SchemaManager.java:554)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.SchemaManager.onCacheTypeCreated(SchemaManager.java:338)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.registerType(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1979)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.registerCache0(GridQueryProcessor.java:2205)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart0(GridQueryProcessor.java:1048)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart(GridQueryProcessor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1968)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.lambda$prepareStartCaches$55a0e703$1(GridCacheProcessor.java:1838)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.lambda$prepareStartCachesIfPossible$14(GridCacheProcessor.java:1808)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareStartCaches(GridCacheProcessor.java:1835)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareStartCachesIfPossible(GridCacheProcessor.java:1806)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.processCacheStartRequests(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:1039)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.onCacheChangeRequest(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:925)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onCacheChangeRequest(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1479)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:986)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3416)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3245)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2SpatialIndex
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2Utils.createSpatialIndex(H2Utils.java:348)
        ... 21 more
```

The above error occurs as soon as I attempt to set `QueryIndexType.GEOSPATIAL` indexes on the `geometry` column of a query entity holding valid JTS geometries. I am able to index these entities when running the Ignite Cluster locally where I am including the `ignite-geospatial` dependency from the GridGain external repository, but am unable to reproduce success within Kubernetes Ignite Cluster.

Java Thick Client pom.xml excerpt

```xml
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>GridGain External Repository</id>
      <url>https://www.gridgainsystems.com/nexus/content/repositories/external</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
   <artifactId>ignite-geospatial</artifactId>
   <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Questions

- Are there alternative methods to loading the `ignite-geospatial` module? Like EXTERNAL_LIBS?
- Are there inherent conflicts with attempting to use this module in a stateless Ignite Cluster deployment?
- I saw `ignite-geospatial` was moved to an Ignite Extension in May 2022, does this impact the way in which Ignite Cluster must enable the module?
- Are there any other troubleshooting measures we can try?

Thank you for your time.